# Is it possible to write a PowerShell prompt function in C# with a CmdLet?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to know if it is possible to override the prompt function using C# code instead of PS1. Like writing a cmdlet or something that customizes the prompt.

Comment: Sure, all you need to do is set the value of the `function:\prompt` item to a scriptblock that returns a string.

Comment: An example? I'm quite new to PS :-)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to update the value of the `prompt` function item.

The simplest `Set-Prompt` cmdlet I can think of would be:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Set, "Prompt")]
public class SetPromptCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ParameterSetName = "ScriptBlock")]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    public ScriptBlock ScriptBlock { get; set; }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        // Overwrite function:\prompt
        InvokeProvider.Item.Set(@"Function:\Prompt", ScriptBlock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't answer the question.  This doesn't originate the prompt function in C#, it just sets it from there.